# How may I arrange classes into packages?

Tags: android, application-design

I've a lots of classes for my SMS Blocker Android application such as:

1. Activity classes
2. Database helper class
3. Data model classes (Java Beans for used by database helper and other classes)
4. Services (Broadcast Receivers etc)
5. Custom list adapters
6. Business process classes
7. A class for application constants
8. A class that performs basic functions used by many classes

What is the right place for each type of class to arrange them inside different packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put classes that are non-activity into the *Classes* folder and put all others into their corresponding folders. It should look like this:

[image: Folder overview]

Comment: What is the right place for data models (Java Bean) classes

Comment: I think you should create response or model folder for that